# How to get the correct file path in firebase update

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use the code below to update the data inside the user admin id.
As the diagram show, I want to edit the value for UserID from test 1 to test3 but after I click on update, it is not update inside the given id. I create another set of data outside the id.
[image: file path in firebase]

```
    firebase.database().ref().child('users/Admin/'+id).update({
         userID:userID,
         name:name,
         email:email,
         password:password,
         phone:phone,
         usertype:usertype,
         registeredDate:field.value
         
     });
```

Comment: I guess id is just empty then?

Comment: Please do some troubleshooting. First check to see what `'users/Admin/'+id` resolves to